# Sequences and patterns: how to avoid loops in R

Tags: r, loops, data-structures, data.table

Because of format requirements of the package I am using for multistate analysis (Biograph), I need to generate a path variable (character variable) with the sequence of states of my respondents.

This can be done easily using the function "Sequences.ind.0" available in the Biograph package, but that function is very inefficient because of loops: it takes more than 20 hours with my actual database (about 5 million of records). I don't know how to get the same result without loops or  faster.

Here I show a simple example with three states (N, P, K), where K is absorbing (i.e. after K there are no additional transitions)

```
dat <- data.table(ID=c(1:5), 
   K=c(NA, 2005, 2004, 2001, 2006), 
   P=c(2001, 1999, 2003, 2003, 1998),
   P=c(2005, 2001, NA, NA, 2001),
   P=c(NA, 2003, NA, NA , 2004),
   N=c(2002, 2000, NA, 2003,2000),
   N=c(NA, 2002, NA, NA, 2003),
   N=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2005))
```

I want to get the path of states for each individual and a matrix with the time in which the change of state occurs. "N" is the initial state, so every sequence should start with "N".  Afterwards, the sequence of states is given by the time in which a transition occurs.

If I use the function "Sequences.ind.0", I get:

```
library(Biograph)
nsample <- nrow(dat)
namstates <- c("N", "P", "K")
f <- Sequences.ind.0(as.matrix(dat[, 2:8, with=FALSE]),namstates,absorb="K")


$namstates
[1] "N" "P" "K"

$d
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] 2001 2002 2005   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,] 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2005   NA
[3,] 2003 2004   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,] 2001   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,] 1998 2000 2001 2003 2004 2005 2006

$path
[1] "NPNP"     "NPNPNPK"  "NPK"      "NK"       "NPNPNPNK"
```

The most important outputs are "path" and "d".
Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions about how to avoid the loops in this case using data.table or another method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify: the basic algorithm is something like "1) sort each row. 2) for each entry in the row, check the year and record the name of its corresponding column (N, P, or K)". Correct?

Comment: Yes! I would add that if K occurs (absorbing state, for instance, death), one can forget the rest of the year and name records. It may be more efficient to do that afterwards. I don't know.

Comment: I don't have a great answer but it seems like this is just not the appropriate data structure for the job

Comment: What would be a better data structure for this?

Comment: it might be better to just have a "dictionary" of years and states like `list(K=c(2001, 2004, 2005, 2006), ...)` , but that's not something I know for sure. I edited in a `data-structures` tag to maybe get some input from the people who are experts in that area.

Comment: How should ties be handled? For example, what if the fourth element's K was 2004.  Would its sequence be NPK or NPNK?

Comment: Ties are always a problem. My data have a small number of ties (I have exact dates). To select randomly between possible states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't benchmark this and more test cases might be good.

```
library(reshape2)
dat1 <- melt(dat, id.vars="ID")
dat1[, na := is.na(value)]
setkeyv(dat1, c("na", "value"))
dat1[, ind := seq_along(value), by=ID]
dat1[, value1 := value]
dat1[, tmp := c(FALSE, head(as.logical(cumsum(variable == "K")), -1)), by=ID]
dat1[dat1[, tmp], value1 := NA]
dat1[ID==1,]

dcast.data.table(dat1[, list(ID, ind, value1)], ID ~ ind)
#    ID    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
# 1:  1 2001 2002 2005   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 2:  2 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2005   NA
# 3:  3 2003 2004   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 4:  4 2001   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# 5:  5 1998 2000 2001 2003 2004 2005 2006

fun <- function(x, b) {
  y <- na.omit(as.character(x)[b])
  if (y[1] != "N") y <- c("N", y)
  paste(y, collapse="")
}
setkey(dat1[, fun(variable, !is.na(value) & !tmp), by=ID], ID)[["V1"]]
#[1] "NPNP"     "NPNPNPK"  "NPK"      "NK"       "NPNPNPNK"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Roland. I am using your great solution with my big dataset. It seems to be working nicely and fast.